# Measure client upstream bandwidth using ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, post, bandwidth

In my struggles to make our customer's experience of our web services as good as possible I am creating a webpage where the individual customer can measure their latency and bandwidth to our site.

Not really a hard task but I need some feedback on how to efficiently measure client upload bandwidth.

Anyone got an exmample/hint on how to create 1-5Mb of data and post it back to the server using jQuery?

BR

/Jens

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this via Google...

http://johan.andersson.net/blog/2009/03/simple-bandwidth-test-based-on-http.html